# How do I get a word frequency count that is grouped by a second variable (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python, so its probable that I am just not wording this properly to find the answer.

Using Pandas I was able to find the most frequent N words for every record in the description field of my data. However, I have two columns; a categorical column and the description field. How to I find the most common word per category?

Ex Data:

```
 - Property|Description
 - House| Blue, Two stories, pool
 - Car| Green, Dented, Manual, New
 - Car| Blue, Automatic, Heated Seat
 - House|New, Furnished, HOA
 - Car|Blue, Old, Multiple Owners
```

My current code will return Blue=3, New=2 etc. But what I need to know is that Blue appeared for the word Car twice and once for House.

Current relevant code

```
words = (data.Description.str.lower().str.cat(sep=' ').split())
keywords=pandas.DataFrame(Counter(words).most_common(10), columns=['Words', 'Frequency'])
```

Comment: Were you helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Property':['House','Car','Car','House','Car'],'Description':['Blue,Two stories,pool','Green,Dented,Manual,New','Blue,Automatic,Heated Seat','Blue,Furnished,HOA','Blue,Old,Multiple Owners']})
```

**Chained solution** `df.assign(words=df.Description.str.lower().str.split(',')).explode('words').groupby('Property')['words'].value_counts()`

**Explanation with a breakdown**

```
#Create list

df['words'] = df.Description.str.lower().str.split(',')

 #Explode and count

df=df.explode('words').groupby('Property')['words'].value_counts()

Property  words          
Car       blue               2
          automatic          1
          dented             1
          green              1
          heated seat        1
          manual             1
          multiple owners    1
          new                1
          old                1
House     blue               2
          furnished          1
          hoa                1
          pool               1
          two stories        1
Name: words, dtype: int64
```

Comment: What `pandas` version are you using? I tried this code under `pandas 0.24.2`and I got following error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'`

Comment: @CedricZoppolo, explode  was introduced in version 0.25.0

Comment: I am on 1.0.4. The latest I think

Comment: You are right @wwnde. Just updated and 1.0.4 is latest pandas version by now.

Comment: Now that I updated the error I was getting is no more. Great answer.

Comment: I wondered how `explode` function works. If anyone wonders as well you can find it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the row values by delimeter then apply [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to transform each element of a list-like to a row, finally [Groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
# remove leading white space's & split by delimiter
df['Description'] = df['Description'].str.strip()\
    .str.replace(",\s+", ",")\
    .str.split(',')

# apply group by to get count of each word.
print(df.explode(column='Description').
      groupby(["Property","Description"]).size().reset_index(name='count'))
```

ouptut,

```
   Property      Description  count
0       Car        Automatic      1
1       Car             Blue      2
2       Car           Dented      1
3       Car            Green      1
4       Car      Heated Seat      1
...
```

Comment: This works after updating pandas to 1.0.4...prior to that the "explode" errored out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use groupby before counting: [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).
and then you can do counting on each group

```
df = pd.DataFrame(...)

groups = df.groupby(['column_name'])
for group in groups:
    do_counting()
```

Comment: I started down this path but after grouping I got an error "Cannot access attribute 'str' of 'SeriesGroupby'. (I changed the df in the description splitter to the the new groupby item). I couldnt figure out how to get at the original field to do the counting.